# LongListSelector Items are not updated due to ToString binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, tostring, longlistselector

I use the LongListSelector to display different items. The items are displayed by a TextBlock which is simply bound to the item itself. So the ToString method is called for each item. This is necessary because the ToString builds the displayed string by appending a few properties and returns them.

The problem is that the LongListSelector can not listen to a PropertyChanged event of a property so the view is not updated automatically. Are there other events which are handled by the LongListSelector and which could be triggered within a property setter?

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ItemLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectItem" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="222,222">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Height="173" MaxHeight="173" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Its not clear what youre asking. You need to provide both front end and back end code

Comment: reassign itemsource of longlist selector may solve your problem.

Comment: This will redraw all items and maybe cause perfomance issues.